# Display images - c# / silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

Experts,

I'm developing an application in Windows phone, Where i need to display images in screen in table format (2 images in row and columns will be growing as required). 
Image count will be dynamic, which i will have the information at runtime.  I need to display all the images

[image: Please see the Image.]

can you please let me know how to proceed.. images will be from internet url.

Pavan

Comment: Will all images have the same width & height?

Comment: yes.. all images with same exact dimention

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a perfect case for the use of the [WrapPanel](http://www.codebadger.com/blog/post/2010/11/10/WP7-Development-Tip-of-the-Day-Silverlight-Toolkit-WrapPanel.aspx) from [Silverlight Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com).

It would basically do precisely what you need, with a single line of code.

Comment: I have used the WrapPanel before for text-items ordered in a same manner, and indeed the WrapPanel is what you're looking for! :)

Comment: I want to add images progrmatically, because i don't know how many images will be there..

Comment: And? Add them to a `ObservableCollection` and there's no problem at all.

Comment: Thanks Claus. Wrap Panel is the best solution

Comment: Any one looking for same kind of issue.. Please refer to this link http://www.kotancode.com/2010/12/29/wp7-presenting-listbox-items-inside-a-wrappanel/

Answer (score 0):

The images will bind to an `ItemsControl`, and then you'll use an `ItemsPanel` to control the layout of each item.

Check out this link for a guide. http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/tips/working-with-itemspanel-in-wp7

Answer (score 0):

I am a kind of beginer but I did it with 4 images and a full screen form. I havent try with C# for Mobile.
Try with this :) code, It will put you only 4 images on anny type of screen Form1 set to start @ center of screen and add set it to full screen mode. After you add 4 imageBox to form and set their image or load it this will set 1 image to 1/4 of full screen.  :

```
public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Location = new Point(Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Left, Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Top);
            this.Size = new Size(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);
            pictureBox1.Size = new Size(this.Width - this.Width / 2, this.Height - this.Height / 2);
            pictureBox1.Location = new Point(0, 0);
            pictureBox2.Size = new Size(this.Width - this.Width / 2, this.Height - this.Height / 2);
            pictureBox2.Location = new Point(this.pictureBox1.Width,0);
            pictureBox3.Size = new Size(this.Width - this.Width / 2, this.Height - this.Height / 2);
            pictureBox3.Location = new Point(0, this.pictureBox1.Height);
            pictureBox4.Size = new Size(this.Width - this.Width / 2, this.Height - this.Height / 2);
            pictureBox4.Location = new Point(this.pictureBox2.Width, this.pictureBox3.Height);
            // this.Controls.Add(pictureBox1);
        }
    }
}
```